# R: Extract row as a new matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix that consist of `nrow = 100` and `ncol = 5` and I want to print every row.

```
d1 <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
d2 <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
d3 <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
d4 <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
d5 <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)

x <- cbind(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5)
x

m <- nrow(x)
n <- ncol(x)

y <- matrix(x, m, n)
y
```

I tried to print every row using looping but it comes out error:

```
for(i in 1:100){
    f[i] = y[i, ]
}
```

My target here is I want to calculate hodges lehmann estimator from every row. Since i have 100 row, meaning to say i'll have 100 estimator. here i put example of coding to calculate hodges lehmann estimator for row 1.

```
f=y[1,]    #row 1
f
n=length(f)
n

#CALCULATE HL
a1<-NULL
a2<-NULL
a3<-NULL
a4<-NULL
a5<-NULL
for (i in 1:n) {
for (j in 1:n) {
if(i==j){
a1[i]<-(f[i]+f[i])/2
}
else if(i!=j&&j-i==1){
a2[i]<-(f[i]+f[i+1])/2
}
else if(i!=j&&j-i==2){
a3[i]<-(f[i]+f[i+2])/2
}
else if(i!=j&&j-i==3){
a4[i]<-(f[i]+f[i+3])/2
}
else if(i!=j&&j-i==4){
a5[i]<-(d1[i]+d1[i+4])/2
}}}
HL1=median(c(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5))    
HL1
```

And that's why I would prefer to use looping. Thanks guys.

Comment: `invisible(apply(matrix(rnorm(100 * 5), 100, 5), 1, print))` maybe, or with a `for` loop, something like `m <- matrix(rnorm(100 * 5), 100, 5); for (j in seq(nrow(m))) print(m[j, ])`. Or just `m` effectively does the same thing.

Comment: the error is due to `y[i,]` being a vector yet you are storing it in `f[i]` which just needs one element. Also maybe because object `f` has not been defined yet

Comment: You haven't set `f <- NULL` beforehand as Onyambu has outlined above. Also, please provide the error you are getting.

Comment: I apologize if I'm being dim, but if you want to print every row, why is `x` or `print(x)` insufficient? Perhaps it would help to provide a bigger picture of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be able to do the trick that you need:

```
  funfun=function(f){s=outer(f,f,"+")/2;median(s[lower.tri(s,T)])}

 apply(data,1,funfun)
```

some explanation:

Your code takes average of the elements that are a certain distance apart:
 eg if you  i==j then simply the diagonal, we will have the elements themselves.
eg if i=j+1,or j=i+1, then it is the (f[i]+f[i+1])/2. That is your code. ETC:

According to thefunction you provided above, if my f=1:5, then I would get:

```
    a1  a2 a3  a4 a5
[1,]  1 1.5  2 2.5  3
[2,]  2 2.5  3 3.5 NA
[3,]  3 3.5  4  NA NA
[4,]  4 4.5 NA  NA NA
[5,]  5  NA NA  NA NA
>
```

Now I have writen a sum `funfun`. If i run this function on 1:5, i get:

```
 s=outer(f,f,"+")/2
 s
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1  1.5  2.0  2.5  3.0
[2,]   NA  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5
[3,]   NA   NA  3.0  3.5  4.0
[4,]   NA   NA   NA  4.0  4.5
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA  5.0
```

What difference do you see? Well the results are the same only the arrangement. In your case, the i==j is the first column, while in my case i==j is the diagonal. in your case i=j+1 or j=i+1 is the second column while mine is the off diagonal. if you want to get exactly as yours we would do

```
s[col(s)==row(s)+1]
[1] 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5
```

Woe now that is exactly same as your second column. Do you see that?.

Okay having now created that function, run it through the whole data rowwise:

Well we can even modify the funfun, if you just understand supply and not outer:

```
 funfun1=function(m){
  n=1:length(m)
  d=sapply(n,function(x)`length<-`((m[x]+m[x>=n])/2,length(m)))
      median(d,na.rm=T)}

 apply(data, 1, funfun1)
```